# simple django join query without foreign key

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset, foreign-key-relationship

**    Below are two models teacher and loginstudent, A teacher can teach multiple sections and multiple students can be in same section.So section field cannot be a foreign key.If I want to find out all courses taken by a particular student,what should I do? Is there any simple django query just like sql did.How to do? 
**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=89)
    course=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    section=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class LoginStudent(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=89)
    section=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to get this done.

Comment: You should check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: @CurseStacker    newobj=teacher.objects.raw('select * from app_teacher t,app_loginstudent l where l.section=t.section and l.username=%s ',[name])     ..name is the student name whose couses i want to list

Comment: Did you mean one loginStudent can only have one section? If so, than one student can only have course, am I understand it correctly?

Comment: @shellbye  no.one loginstudent have only one section,but many courses can be in same section,so student can have multiple courses

Comment: Teacher teaches one or many courses. Courses belongs to sections (btw: only one section or a course can appear to several sections?). Student attends only to sections. Did I get this right ?

Comment: @Roba .yea,it's right and many courses can be for same section.so all students of same section takes same courses.I hope it's clear.

Comment: Before asking questions like these, you should consider learning about Third Normal Form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form Not handling obvious data design flaws like this up-front will cost you a lot of blood, sweat and tears down the road. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I would recommend to stick to the default user system from Django and build one-to-one profiles of the specific type where needed. Latter on you can differentiate between the users based on the value of the foreign key or you could implement permissions which are tied to the user type

```python
from django.db.models.query_utils import Q


# for example, this could be a way to extend users to hold teachers and students
class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='teacher_profile')
    # other relevant teacher profile items
ONLY_TEACHERS_FILTER = Q(teacher_profile__isnull=False) & Q(student_profile__isnull=True)


class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='student_profile')
    # other relevant student profile items
    sections = models.ManyToManyField('Section', related_name='students')   # mind the quotes to Section name


class Section(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # other section fields goes here...


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teacher = models.ForeingKey(User, related_name='courses', limit_choices_to=ONLY_TEACHERS_FILTER)
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section, related_name='courses')
```

Now to answer to the question what are the courses to which a student attends to:

```python
queryset = Course.objects.filter(section__students__in=[user])
```

Hope it helps!